# JSON Schema Requirement Enforcement

Tags: php, json, jsonschema

So this is my first time using JSON Schema and I have a fairly basic question about requirements.

My top level schema is as follows:

schema.json:

```
{
    "id": "http://localhost/srv/schemas/schema.json",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "event": { "$ref": "events_schema.json#" },
        "building": { "$ref": "buildings_schema.json#" }
    },
    "required": [ "event" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I have two other schema definition files (events_schema.json and buildings_schema.json) that have object field definitions in them.  The one of particular interest is buildings_schema.json.

buildings_schema.json:

```
{
    "id": "http://localhost/srv/schemas/buildings_schema.json",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "buildings table validation definition",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "BuildingID": {
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 1
        },
        "BuildingDescription": {
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 255
        }
    },
    "required": [ "BuildingID" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I am using this file to test my validation:

test.json:

```
{
    "event": {
        "EventID": 1,
        "EventDescription": "Some description",
        "EventTitle": "Test title",
        "EventStatus": 2,
        "EventPriority": 1,
        "Date": "2007-05-05 12:13:45"
    },
    "building": {
        "BuildingID": 1,
    }
}
```

Which passes validation fine.  But when I use the following:

test2.json

```
{
    "event": {
        "EventID": 1,
        "EventDescription": "Some description",
        "EventTitle": "Test title",
        "EventStatus": 2,
        "EventPriority": 1,
        "Date": "2007-05-05 12:13:45"
    }
}
```

I get the error: `[building] the property BuildingID is required`

Inside my buildings_schema.json file I have the line `"required": [ "BuildingID" ]` which is what causes the error.  It appears that the schema.json is traversing down the property definitions and enforcing all the requirements.  This is counter intuitive and I would like it to ONLY enforce a requirement if it's parent property is enforced.

I have a few ways around this that involve arrays and fundamentally changing the structure of the JSON, but that kind of defeats the purpose of my attempts at validating existing JSON.  I have read over the documentation (/sigh) and have not found anything relating to this issue.  Is there a some simple requirement inheritance setting I am missing?

I am using the Json-Schema for PHP implementation from here: https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema

Comment: The problem might be in the way you are referencing schemas. Have you tried to put the definition of schema, buildings_schema and events_schema in the same file with relative refs? Perhaps we could identify where the problem is, or in file resolution and schema hierarchy or in the validator itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing with different validators, it appears to be an issue with the validator. The validator assumes required inheritance through references. I fixed this by simply breaking apart the main schema into subschemas and only using the required subschema when necessary.